# Блок накладывается на другой

Tags: html, css

У меня блок в которым элементы располагаются вертикально, но третий элемент накладывается на второй, подскажите как исправить

```css
.about{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

.postavshiki{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.yrface{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-content">
                   <div class="about">
                       <a href="#" class="footer-link"> О нас</a>
                   </div>
               </div>
                <div class="footer-content">
                   <div class="postavshiki">
                       <a href="#" class="footer-link"> Поставщикам</a>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="footer-content">
                   <div class="yrface">
                       <a href="#" class="footer-link"> Юрлицам</a>
                   </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам просто нужно расположить эти элементы вертикально нужно просто сделать так:

```
        <div class="content">
                   
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> О нас</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Поставщикам</a></div>
                   <div><a href="#" class="footer-link"> Юрлицам</a></div>
          </div>  `
```

css:

```
      .content{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
       }
```

[Вот ссылка на эту тему(Flex)](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/)